# Flask App: Load images from current working directory

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

**tl;dr version: how do I get my Flask app to load images not in the project directory?**

I am building (as a fun project) a Flask app, designed as a command-line app, that loads a random image from my current working directory in the browser. Here is what the app structure looks like.

```
+-- imgdisplay/
    +-- imgdisplay/
        +-- imgdisplay.py
        +-- static/
            +-- styling.css
        +-- templates/
            +-- img.html
    +-- setup.py
    +-- LICENSE
    +-- README.md
```

My `setup.py` has a `entry_points` keyword argument that is as follows:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'imgdisplay=imgdisplay.imgdisplay:start_server'
    ]
```

This lets me start the command-line app `imgdisplay` from anywhere. I have verified that this portion works with no problem.

My `imgdisplay.py` code looks like the following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import webview
import click
from random import choice
import os
import os.path as osp
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)


# logging.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

@app.route('/')
def hello(name=None):
    files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
    image = choice([f for f in files if f[-4:] == '.jpg'])
    # tried the following line, but didn't work.
    # image = osp.join(os.getcwd(), image)
    # logging.info(image)
    return render_template('img.html', name=name, files=files, image=image)


@click.command()
@click.option('--port', default=5000, help='Port', prompt='Port')
@click.option('--host', default='localhost', help='Host', prompt='Host')
def start_server(port=5000, host='localhost'):
    app.run(host='localhost', port=port)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server()
```

My `img.html` template looks like the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styling.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <title>Hello from Flask</title>
    {% if name %}
      <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
    {% else %}
      <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    {% endif %}

    {{ image }}

    {% if image %}
      <img src="{{ image }}"></img>
    {% endif %}

</body>
```

All in all, it's a very simple Flask app. Something a noob like me would build.

On my Desktop, I have a folder called `images/`, in which I put a single image. I can display the file name string in my browser, but I cannot display the image; I expect to see the image loaded in the browser, but all I get is the icon showing that the image cannot be found. Pardon my noobness here, but what's the crucial concept I'm missing here?

Comment: In case anybody wants context, I'm trying to build this as the front-end interface to a folder in which I can drop in new images and reload in the browser, using a Raspberry Pi. Trying to get creative here :-)

Comment: That's been stated in the text. "I can display the image filename in the browser, but cannot display the image."

Comment: I'm sorry, but I sense frustration coming from this perception that I'm a newbie SO user. What I've shown is precisely what I've done so far. My web dev experience is close to nil; most of my SO experience has been in the data science world. Here's my response to your questions: I don't request for the image, but should I be doing so? There's no error thrown here, and I have set up static dirs (see the directory structure posted right at the top).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131430/discussion-between-ericmjl-and-pvg).

Comment: Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask which is more or less a dupe of this, once you get down to the actual issue

Comment: flask doc: [send_from_directory()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_from_directory) and [send_file()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_file)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41316717/5802335 your answer is here.

Comment: @metmirr: thanks, that was really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can display the file name string in my browser

It 's not a browser's network feature, it's a browser local file system feature, however, when you put the path such as `/home/yetship/images/test.jpg` in the html like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
       <img src="/home/yetship/images"></img>
    </body>
</html>
```

it's sure it will be not work, because if you visit you website in url: `http://localhost:8080`, the img tag will not find image in your pc with path `/home/yetship/images` instead, it will find images in `http://localhost:8080/home/yetship/images`,so, if you want make it display, you should following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask) to make your `image` directory a static directory and you should make `img` tag as:

```
<img src="image/test.jpg"></img>
```

instead of

```
<img src="/home/yetship/image/test.jpg"></img>
```

and flask will find the image in your `image` directory and display on you browser.

I hope this can help you.